Client asking for new invoice for 2nd installment?
A client received an invoice from me for my services.
One instalment was due to be paid immediately, the 2nd instalment due 3 months later.
The 3 month mark has come and the client has asked that I provide a new invoice for the 2nd installment. They say their accounting system does not allow for the same invoice to be paid twice.
My accounting system is not set up for this.
If I provide a new invoice with new invoice numbers, my system will forever show the 2nd instalment of the 1st invoice as unpaid.
We are stuck here.
They say they cannot pay the same invoice twice.
I say I cannot issue a new invoice.
Does anyone have a solution or experience with this?
Thank you so much for your time.

Can you build a fake invoice in Excel that you can send them? Or can you post a payment to an invoice and then post an offsetting credit memo of the same amount?

Ridiculous system if you need to send a new invoice to show a previous invoice has been paid. It is your system which is flawed.

Are you or your client really using accounting systems that don't understand Statements, as opposed to Invoices? Either way, can your own system not accommodate unpaid amounts?
After all that, how does this actually relate to SE Freelancing rather than somewhere dealing with Accounting, Book-keeping or, come to that, Invoicing?

Every installment requires a different invoice, with a different number. This is how it normally works.

I don't think it's unreasonable for the client to expect a new invoice number. I would create 2 more invoices. Let's say your original invoice number was 1000. I would create 1000-1 to represent installment #1, and 1000-2 to represent installment #2.  Mark #1 as paid and send #2 to the client. Obviously you would cancel #1 (but not send notification to the client of that).

Kind thanks everyone !
All your answers helped.
It is interesting how the only way through this is to cancel an invoice (without telling client about it) or to fake an invoice.
That there is no clear straight forward no funny business way of doing it.
I don't think my system is flawed - I can show an invoice as paid.
That wasn't the problem. The problem was a new invoice being required for the 2nd instalment of the 1st invoice. The missing instalment in the 1st invoice would forever show as unpaid / show up in debtors later. I wanted to avoid that.
